# Creating a Table using LuaLaTex

Tags: tables, luatex

I am just trying to create a simple table in LuaLaTex that summarizes an experiment. I needed to use it (LuaLaTex) to typset my document in Times New Roman font.

I am using Macbook Pro with OSX El Capitan. I have the latest version of LaTex installed for my OS.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a bit more information about this mysterious table. E.g., how many rows and columns is it supposed to have? Will you be using "straight" LaTeX methods to create the table, or is there some Lua-specific programming involved? Can you at least post a scan of a hand-sketched outline of the table structure?

Comment: My apologies! 

If there's a way to use just the "straight" LaTex methods, that'd be ideal.

I'm just looking for a simple table:
Title, two columns, with ten rows. That's it!

Comment: example `\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Team sheet} \\
  \hline
  GK & Paul Robinson \\
  LB & Lucas Radebe \\
  DC & Michael Duberry \\
  DC & Dominic Matteo \\
  RB & Dider Domi \\
  MC & David Batty \\
  MC & Eirik Bakke \\
  MC & Jody Morris \\
  FW & Jamie McMaster \\
  ST & Alan Smith \\
  ST & Mark Viduka \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}`  from https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables

Comment: thank you @touhami! That was extremely helpful! I can figure it out from there! I didn't know if it was as easy as using {tabular} and \hline. Turns out, it is! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't exactly provided a lot of details about the table you wish to create. In the following example, a `table` environment is set up to house a `\caption` (along with a `\label` so that the table may be cross-referenced elsewhere in the document) as well as a  two-column `tabular` environment. The macros `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` -- all provided by the `booktabs` package -- are used to draw well-spaced horizontal rules.

For more introductory-level information about how to create tables in LaTeX, I would like to suggest you read sections 2.11.6 ("tabular") and 2.12 ("floating bodies") of the [The not so Short Introduction to LaTeX2e](http://mirrors.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf). The [user guide of the booktabs package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf) provides excellent information on how to go about creating professional-looking tables.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times Roman} % Times Roman text font
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{A two-column table}
\label{tab:twocol}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
Head1 & Head2 \\
\midrule
a & b \\
c & d \\
e & f \\
g & h \\
i & j \\
k & l \\
m & n \\
o & p \\
q & r \\
s & t \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I appreciate the resource you offered. Didn't know where to look specifically. I have some reading to do!

Comment: @Mico, consider being clear that there's nothing Lua specific about it...

Comment: @PTNobel - Maybe not Lua-specific, but there's `\usepackage{fontspec}` and `\setmainfont{Times Roman}` in the preamble, both to pick up one of the few details the OP provided... Both instructions work only with LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX...